# Inheriting constructors of template class in c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In c++11 it is possible to inherit constructors. I have the following code (reproducing example), which fails to compile:

```
template<class T> class A
{
    ...
}

template<class T> class B : public A<T>
{
    public:       
        B(int a, int b = 0);
}
template<class T> B::B(int a, int b /* =0 */)
{
    ...
}

class C : public B<int>
{
    public: 
    using B::B;
}
```

The following code doesn't run with the error that `C` doesn't have the constructor, i.e. the one from `B` is not inherited:

```
C obj(5);
//or
C obj(5, 3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 does *not* support inheriting constructors. See [Support For C++11 Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) for more information. Here's the relevant part:

> C++11 Core Language Features
>
> - inheriting constructors
>
>   - Visual Studio 2010: No
>   - Visual Studio 2012: No
>   - Visual Studio 2013: No

**Update**

Looks like support for inheriting constructors was [added in the November 2013 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx) (hat tip: @yngum)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your original code is that `B::B` is private, so make it `public`.

```
template<class T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:   // THIS
    B(int a, int b = 0);
}
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e31502335b6194f)

Comment: @user2028058 I've posted a live example, and it compiles. Are you sure that the code you've posted gives out the said error?

Comment: @user2028058 If you're in GCC or clang, you should compile it with `-std=c++11`. And make sure the version supports C++11.

Comment: I'll check this. It should be some other problem. Initial question eliminated. Thanks!

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2013. Do you know how to check the support of inheriting constructors?

Comment: @user2028058 they just added support for inheriting constructor _today_. [November CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit a constructor, but you can call it explicitly in the initialization list of the derived class.

```
class C: public B<int>
{
    C(int a, int b=0) : B(a, b)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

though the answer of @godel9 is still right (in 2022),
you can use the following trick (in VS2013 / vc120):

```
using std::forward;
class Aaa : public Bbb {
public:
  Aaa() : Bbb() {}
  template<class A>  explicit Aaa(A a):Bbb(forward<A>(a)) {}
  template<class A,class B>  Aaa(A a,Bbb b):Bbb(forward<A>(a),forward<B>(b)) {}
};
```

This inherits (or better "forwards") the zero-/one-/two-argument ctors.
Of course you have to repeat this for 3, 4, 5, .. arguments.