# Is inheriting constructors part of the standard?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constructor

I just learned today that it's possible to inherit a constructor with a `using` statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20062289/5987

The question is if this is specified by the standard or if it's an extension by certain compilers. If it is part of the standard, was it introduced in C++11?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's standard. Yes, it was added in C++11:

C++11 § 12.9 Inheriting Constructors [class.inhctor]:

> A *using-declaration* (7.3.3) that names a constructor implicitly declares a set of *inheriting constructors*. The
>   *candidate set of inherited constructors* from the class `X` named in the *using-declaration* consists of actual
>   constructors and notional constructors that result from the transformation of defaulted parameters as follows:
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

It was introduced in the C++11, but as mentionned in the previous question, since it is fairly new, only a few compilers support this feature.

Comment: Well, GCC and Clang have both supported it for a while now, and MSVC supports it as of the new CTP. Those are probably the three most commonly used compilers. I'm not sure whether Intel's has it yet.